# How does efs pricing works lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lambda, amazon-efs

Does the pricing only applicable for storage or there are also other charges associated wit it?

for eg: if a lambda function puts 1Gb/s of file on efs via a private vpc then how much it will charge for a day?

On aws efs pricing page they've mentioned:

```
Total EFS One Zone storage charge: 74,400 GB-Hours x (1 month / 744 hours) x $0.16/GB-month = $16
```

but does not tell if there are any other cost is associated or not?

Is there also a cost to put/delete file on efs?

Answer (score 0):

The [EFS pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/pricing/) says you're charged for storage, not bandwidth. The [lambda pricing page](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/) says traffic to EFS is free.

If you're reading 1Gbps from EFS it's free.

Writing 1Gbps is 450GB/hr, which is 10.8TB / month. According to the AWS calculator cost 10.8TB will cost USD$884 per month. If you assume EFS is empty beforehand your average storage for the month is 5.4TB which means your total EFS charge is US$442 for the month and each subsequent month. That doesn't include lambda charges.

S3 has cheaper storage.